# Limit with Zero Denominator

Tags: calculus, limits

Given $\lim_\limits{x \to 3} f(x) = -4$ and $\lim_\limits{x \to 3} g(x) = 0$, what is
$\lim_\limits{x \to 3} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$?

I don't think we can't just say $\lim_\limits{x \to 3} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_\limits{x \to 3} f(x)}{\lim_\limits{x \to 3} g(x)} = DNE$ because the bottom is zero, yet my text gives $DNE$ as the solution.  Can we indeed take the ratio of the limits even though the bottom is zero?  Or, am I correct in thinking this question is ill-posed?

Comment: It's ill posed. Maybe $g(x)=0$ forall $x$

Comment: Does "I don't think we can't just say" mean "I think we can say" or "I don't think we can say"? I suppose your book uses "DNE" to mean "does not exist." Do you disagree with the answer in the book (that is, do you think the limit exists)?

Comment: Yes, it's ill-posed: if $g(x)=|x|$, then clearly $\lim_{x\to3}f(x)/g(x)=-\infty$. On the other hand, if $g(x)=x$, the limits from the left and from the right differ (the former is $\infty$ and the latter is $-\infty$). And for $g(x)=0$ the limit doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of ratios equals ratios of limits if and only if the limit exists.
So no, it's incorrect to split it here (handy tool btw - if you try splitting and the ratio of limits comes out to be finite, then the limit of ratios will have the same value THUS it was okay to split it in first place).

Depending if $g(x) = |g(x)|$ around $x=3$ the answer would be DNE or infinite.

($\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x} = DNE$ but $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{|x|} = \infty$)